# Latest Value for row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've created a VIEW to get a list of people who work and their hourly rates.
The problem that I can't solve is that when there are people who got their hourly rate increased, the employee record is shown twice.

I'll illustrate how I currently have it in the below table:

```
Employee_ID  Hourly_rate Hours_8_2015 Hours_9_2015 Hours_10_2015 Hours_11_2015 
A001             5.8            20         30             25           30                 
A002             5.8            25         00             00           00        
A002             5.9            00         30             00           00        
A002             6.2            00         00             25           20      
A003             5.9            20         30             30           25        
A004             6.0            20         30             00           00        
A004             6.3            00         00             25           20
```

Rather than hours worked against corresponding hourly rates as above what I'd like to see is their latest hourly rate and the hours they've worked each month. Like this:

```
Employee_ID  Hourly_rate Hours_8_2015 Hours_9_2015 Hours_10_2015 Hours_11_2015 
A001             5.8            20         30             25           30                 
A002             6.2            25         30             25           20      
A003             5.9            20         30             30           25        
A004             6.3            20         30             25           20
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a primary key or a datetime column so you know what constitutes the latest?

Comment: Look up `top-n-per-group` or `greatest-n-per-group`. For SQL Server see [Retrieving n rows per group‌​](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group).

Comment: Can you show your select query?

Comment: Pretty bad sample data and no own effort shown. In this sample you can use `MAX` or `SUM`, you haven't mentioned any edge cases and what should happen then(f.e. decreasing values)

Comment: You need a ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_ID  ORDER BY primarykey DESC) and then you use rn=1

Comment: *"[...]what I'd like to see is their latest hourly rate[...]"*. How is it determined what the *latest* hourly rate is... on what column should this be based?

Comment: Hourly_rates can go down, even though it's not shown on the Example. Hence I can't use MAX

What I mean by latest Hourly rate is, the Hourly rate an employee was entitled for the latest work month, in this case 11_2015. For example from the table, A002 has had 3 hourly rates over the months. 5.8 during 8_2015, 5.9 during 9_2015 and 6.2 during 10_2015 and 11_2015

Comment: @Tim Schmelter                                                                   Hourly_rates can go down, even though it's not shown on the Example. Hence I can't use MAX.                                                               What I mean by latest Hourly rate is, the Hourly rate an employee was entitled for the latest work month, in this case 11_2015. For example from the table, A002 has had 3 hourly rates over the months. 5.8 during 8_2015, 5.9 during 9_2015 and 6.2 during 10_2015 and 11_2015

Comment: @TT hope the above answers your question.

Comment: It answers it... but with the table you gave as an example there is no way to tell which hourly_rate to choose other than the order in which the rows are given. Alas tables are inherently **unordered** so there is no way to pick just the last row for eg Employee_ID=A002. If there were an ID column that always increases, that would change the matter.

Comment: @TT.Hence I have mentioned 'Latest' meaning the hourly_rate one is paid during the latest month. I can add another column if I wanted. but how do I add a self increasing column?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
       MAX(HOURLY_RATE),
       sum(Hours_8_2015),
       sum(hours_9_2015),
       sum(Hours_10_2015),
       sum(Hours_11_2015)
from YourTable 
group by EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Use group by for that matter.

Comment: Needs to be latest value, cant be MAX as Hourly Rates can go down

Comment: In this EXAMPLE,  increased! it's common sense that Hourly_rates can go up and also down. However,I did not Down vote your answer. WHY WOULD I !!!!
for the record I cant down vote anyone even if I wanted to my profile score isn't high enough to vote anyone!!

Comment: As I said before to you my very knowledgeable friend, I cant down vote anyone even if I wanted to my profile score isn't high enough to vote anyone!!

Comment: @SanjayaWeerakkody I understand, so do you want to tell me how should i know which rate to take?

Comment: @sagi How you should know this is by me telling you what it is. which isn't very clear in my initial question. The Latest one someone is paid at, in this case is the rate paid on 11_2015.

Comment: @SanjayaWeerakkody But what about people that stopped working before? lets say 10_2015. What would you do then?

Comment: @sagi they would have the rate they got paid on 10_2015 wish would be what they'd be paid at if they still worked for them that 11_2015 column would be 00 . that's why I've said the latest Rate. the rate is updated for an employee every time there's a rate hike or a decrease

Comment: @SanjayaWeerakkody Well, for that I would offer you to add another column, ind_valid, and every time a rate is updated, the old one becomes 0 and the new one becomes 1. Is this possible?